# Why does Google satellite layer change the project CRS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have a project and a topomap in WGS84 (EPSG4326).
On the fly CRS transformation is activated.
I open Google satellite layer from the OpenLayers plugin.
The Google layer is WGS84 / Pseudo Mercator (EPSG3857).
But then the whole project has also become WGS84 / Pseudo Mercator (EPSG3857).

I thought on the fly transformation would reproject to EPSG4326. Why is that? Is it better to work directly in WGS84 / Pseudo Mercator (EPSG3857) systematically when we use Google Earth?

Answer (score 8):

The Openlayers plugin fetches tiles from Google or Openstreetmap servers which come in EPSG:3857. If you would reproject them to another CRS tile by tile, the result would look rather ugly. That's why the developer decided to insist on the project CRS bound to EPSG:3857, so that every other data gets reprojected, but not the tiles. And that is the same the original Openlayers works.

A solution would be to download all relevant tiles, stitch them together, reproject and display the result. But that would take too much time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way to correct that. Apparently the problem appear only using Bing from OpenLayers plugin, however the QuickMapServices plugin also have the Bing and this one don't have this problem. I don't really know why the problem exists, maybe a bug on the plugin, but to fix the problem I use the Bing from QuickMapServices.