# Coordinates system in degrees in plugins for QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, qgis-openlayers-plugin

After adding a vector layer of coordinates of settlements of a part of the world INTO QGIS 1.8, I wish to add a topographic or other nice looking, colored map. Trying plugins like maps from Google Earth changes the coordinate system into meters, This has the consequence that I cannot lable coordinates in degrees with a grid. Are there plugins of a world map that can be displayed in degrees in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Use Open Layer Plugin .In this Plugin there are number of maps available where you can the coordinate system into meters or degree minutes and seconds also.I think this may help you.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, however it appears you have not understood my question. I repeat: adding any of the open layer pluggins changes the coordinate system from degrees to meters, and I cannot find any way to change the coordinate system back to degrees by selecting a different coordinate system with the button at the lower right designed for that. My layer starts with EPSG4326, after adding an open layer pluggin the map presents itself in EPSG3857 (units apparently in meters) and I cannot get back to degrees. Hence my question: Is there a world map plugin that agrees to be in deg

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57151/why-does-google-satellite-layer-change-the-project-crs check this answer

Answer (score 0):

Natural Earth offers coastlines as well as degree grids for the whole globe:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/

These can be added even if the project CRS must be in metres, as the Openlayers plugin requires.